# Restrictions with analytic queries in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a use case where I want to group on several columns and aggregate on a particular column over partitions which are subsets of the columns in the `group by` clause.

Example Scenario

Table Schema:

`(id int, category1 string, category2 string, category3 string, value int)`

I want to execute the following query:

```
select sum(value) over (partition by category1) as c1_sum, sum(value) over (partition by category2) as c2_sum, sum(value) over (partition by category3) as c3_sum from <table_name> group by category_1, category2, category3;
```

However hive complains that the column `value` is not a part of the `group by` clause.

Is there a different way to achieve this in hive?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying can be done. Say cat1 has 2 distinct values, cat2 has 3 and cat3 has 5. You are asking hive (or any of his friends) to return 2 rows on cat1 , 3 rows on cat2 and 5 on cat3. Furthermore, how to match these into a dataset is beyond any logic imho. But why don't use unions like

```
Select category1 as cat, sum (value) as sumCat 
 from tblName 
group by category1 
Union 
Select category2 as cat, sum (value) as sumCat 
  from tblName 
group by category2
Union 
Select category3 as cat, sum (value) as sumCat 
  from tblName 
group by category3
```